# If X determines Y can then Y be a set?

Tags: sql, database, math, database-design, normalization

This is my question regarding database normalization, which is very much related to functional dependencies.

My question is regarding the table below:

> { ID, NR_ID, IMPRESSION_TYPE, VALUE}

```
Say ID -> NR_ID, ID->IMPRESSION_TYPE, ID->Value. 
Also, { NR_ID, IMPRESSION_TYPE } -> VALUE.
```

So can I say, `ID -> { NR_ID, IMPRESSION_TYPE }` thus beating the rule for 3NF that states there should be no transitive dependencies?

Comment: [In relational database theory, a functional dependency is a constraint between two sets of attributes in a relation from a database.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency). Is this an answer for your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So can I say, ID -> { NR_ID, IMPRESSION_TYPE } thus beating the rule
>   for 3NF that states there should be no transitive dependencies?

No, you can't make a transitive dependency go away by rearranging the terms.

Dependencies are based on sets. The expression A->B means "the set of attributes called 'A' determines the set of attributes called 'B'". Date says, "Basically, a functional dependency . . . is a *many-to-one relationship* from one **set of attributes** to another within a given relvar." (Date, *An Introduction to Database Systems*, 7th ed, p 330. Emphasis added.)

Second, [Armstrong's axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms) (decomposition) say that`ID -> { NR_ID, IMPRESSION_TYPE }` is equivalent to `ID -> NR_ID, ID->IMPRESSION_TYPE`. That doesn't imply that ID no longer determines Value, or that { NR_ID, IMPRESSION_TYPE } no longer determines Value.

Comment: Maybe I put it in the wrong way, but I meant that since ID -> { NR_ID, IMPRESSION_TYPE } exists and { NR_ID, IMPRESSION_TYPE } -> Value exists, the table is not in 3NF.

Comment: That's right. It's not in 3NF, because there's a transitive dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ofcourse it's having transitive dependency. Because

ID can determine value ie `(ID-->Value)`
NR_ID and IMPRESSION_TYPE can determine value ie

```
 ( NR_ID, IMPRESSION_TYPE --> Value)
```

So this is in 2NF form and transitive dependency has to be removed to make it 3NF and
my suggestion is to have ID and Value in another table

Comment: U mean NR_ID, IMPRESSION_TYPE and Value in another table?

Comment: My idea is to have ID,NR_ID and IMPRESSION_TYPE in one table and ID,Value in another table. Is this misleading?

Comment: Very good question too buddy @PrathikRajendranM. Are you a data warehouse developer??